# Unable to view the desktop after restart

Tags: 16.04

After setting Java Path and do restart, I was unable to view the desktop, upper right corner controls and left side bar. I able to login with credentials. After that nothing can be done. Just only the purple color window. Unable to do my work. I have shared the image similar to my scenario.

[image]

Comment: Also try `sudo rm .Xauthority` from `tty1`.